# Java serialization -- exception when work around transient object

Tags: java, serialization

### UPDATE

Thanks everyone for the great assistance, here I have to add one possible reason regarding the exception:

If you add `readObject()` and `writeObject()` in the domain classes(like class college below) and also you have to call `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject()` method in main() method, then make sure:

---Do not place `ObjectOutputStream.close()` method in the domain class. It will cause exception because then it is illegal to operate on that object since it is closed(how can the program read the file or close the file after it have been already closed?).

I know it is a minor issue but quite subtle to debug as the exception will not tell anything about it. So this is a little bit of heads up for the record.

---

I try to implement a simple snippet to compromise serialization on transient object, which is serialize the primitive fields of that transient object, then deserialize those primitive fields by the ObjectInputStream, finally compose a new object with them. The scenario is like this:

```
public class College implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private transient City city; //transient
    private String zipCode;

    // constructors & getter/setters

private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os){
    try {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
        os.writeInt(city.getCode());
        os.writeInt(city.getPopulation());
        os.writeObject(city.getName());
        os.flush();
        os.close(); // update: not good practice, may throw exception.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void readObject(ObjectInputStream os){
    try {
        os.defaultReadObject();
        int code = os.readInt();
        int population = os.readInt();
        String name = (String)os.readObject();
        City theCity = new City(code, name, population);
        System.out.println(theCity.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
}
```

Here is the City class

```
public class City {
    // the primitive & String fields
    private int code;
    private String name;
    private int population;

    // getter/setters

}
```

And here is the lovely code to write and read the `college` object(a little bit chunky, sorry)

```
public class GeneralTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    City city = new City(375, "New York", 380897);
    College college = new College("NYU", city, "10289");
    College readCollege = null;
    City readCity = null;
    
    System.out.println("Before serialization -- City: ["+city.toString()+"], College: ["+college.toString()+"]");
    
    try {
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("college.foo");
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        os.writeObject(college);
        os.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("college.foo");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        readCollege = (College)ois.readObject();

        //get values to compose a city object
        int id = ois.readInt();
        int population = ois.readInt();
        String name = ois.readUTF();
        readCity = new City(id, name, population);
        
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    System.out.println("After serialization -- City: ["+readCity.toString()+"], College: ["+readCollege.toString()+"]");
}

}
```

And then I got this exceptions and the `readCollege` and `readCity` are apparently null :(

```
java.io.IOException: Write error
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.drain(ObjectOutputStream.java:1847)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream$BlockDataOutputStream.setBlockDataMode(ObjectOutputStream.java:1756)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNonProxyDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1257)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeClassDesc(ObjectOutputStream.java:1211)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1395)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFatalException(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:333)
    at serialized.GeneralTest.main(GeneralTest.java:27)
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2721)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFChar(ObjectInputStream.java:3113)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTFBody(ObjectInputStream.java:3010)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:2819)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1050)
    at serialized.College.readObject(College.java:70)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at serialized.GeneralTest.main(GeneralTest.java:40)
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2553)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.skipCustomData(ObjectInputStream.java:1899)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1873)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at serialized.GeneralTest.main(GeneralTest.java:40)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at serialized.GeneralTest.main(GeneralTest.java:52)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute this line:

```
readCollege = (College)ois.readObject();
```

There's nothing anymore in the stream afterwards.

So your futur attempt to reading the same stream throw a logically `java.io.EOFException`:
(Besides, notice the replacement of `readUTF()` by `readObject()`)

```
//get values to compose a city object
        int id = ois.readInt();   // there's nothing more !! throws exception!
        int zip = ois.readInt();
        String name = (String)ois.readObject();
```

Indeed, you haven't added your custom values while writing to the stream.

So,one example of solution, add the three lines dedicated to adding elements needed for `City`:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("college.foo");
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
        os.writeObject(college);
        os.writeInt(1); //adding the id !
        os.writeInt(75019); //adding the zip !
        os.writeObject("name"); //adding the name !
        os.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Of course, order of read fields has to be the **same** of the one during writing.

**UPDATE AFTER YOUR COMMENT:**

In fact, you already read the custom values for `City` within `College` class through your `readObject()` method, so these lines are useless:

```
int id = ois.readInt();
int population = ois.readInt();
String name = (String)ois.readObject();   // remove them all
```

Why ??? Because they merely throw the `java.io.EOFException` since nothing more to read as I explained before.

Here a working global code:

```
class College implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private transient City city; //transient
    private String zipCode;

    College(String name, City city, String zipCode) {
        this.name = name;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream os) {
        try {
            os.defaultReadObject();
            int code = os.readInt();
            int population = os.readInt();
            String name = (String) os.readObject();
            this.city = new City(code, name, population);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) {
        try {
            os.defaultWriteObject();
            os.writeInt(1);
            os.writeInt(200);
            os.writeObject("thename");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public City getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(City city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getZipCode() {
        return zipCode;
    }

    public void setZipCode(String zipCode) {
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }
}

class City {
    // the primitive & String fields
    private int code;
    private String name;
    private int population;

    City(int code, String name, int population) {
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.population = population;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }

    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;
    }

    // getter/setters
}

public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        City city = new City(375, "New York", 380897);
        College college = new College("NYU", city, "10289");
        College readCollege = null;
        City readCity = null;

        System.out.println("Before serialization -- City: [" + city.toString() + "], College: [" + college.toString() + "]");

        try {
            FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("college.foo");
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
            os.writeObject(college);
            os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("college.foo");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            readCollege = (College) ois.readObject();
            readCity = readCollege.getCity();

            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("After serialization -- City: [" + readCity.toString() + "], College: [" + readCollege.toString() + "]");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Mik378. Then how can we solve this situation when we really want to pass additional values from transient object into the `OutputStream` object, so that when ObjectInputStream can read the file and we can pick up the value to compose that transient object?

Comment: thank you. Sorry I miss the writeObject() and readObject() method in college class, I have updated the code on the post. So the read and write section is in college class. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Thumbs up for the great answer ! :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's your section of code that outputs

```
    FileOutputStream fs = new FileOutputStream("college.foo");
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fs);
    os.writeObject(college);
    os.close();
```

You create your stream, you write the `college` object, and you close it.

Here's you're reading part:

```
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("college.foo");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    readCollege = (College)ois.readObject();
```

At this point, you've already read everything you've written. You wrote college before, and now you read it.

Then you go and do this:

```
    //get values to compose a city object
    int id = ois.readInt();
    int population = ois.readInt();
    String name = ois.readUTF();
    readCity = new City(id, name, population);
```

How can you expect to be reading anything here? You only wrote `college`. Then you read `college` back in (into the `readCollege` reference. Then you're trying to read two more ints and a String? Where is that data supposed to come from? There's nothing left to read.

Comment: thank you but that didn't solve the exception. Actually I think there is something wrong when doing the `writeObject` part...

Comment: sorry my bad, there is a type and I just fix it. City get a `population` instead of `zipCode`, which is a integer.

Comment: I found a big problem that I've added in.

Answer (score 1):

replace your ois.readUTF() with ois.readObject() and cast it to a String.

```
String name = (String) ois.readObject();
```

didn't compile/tried that...